# Rails: multiple associations query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I have associations like this: Profession -> orders -> profile -> location

```
Class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: orders
end

Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profession
  belongs_to :profile
end

Class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location
  has_many :orders
end

Class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :profile
end
```

And I need to find a professions which are in the location.city.
For example I try this:

```
Profession.joins(:orders).where(orders: {profile: {location: {city: "Simferopol"}}})
```

Is this possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider an association using through:

```
class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :profiles, through: :orders 
end
```

This may make life easier for you allowing you to call:

```
Profession.profiles
```

This will return all profiles for a given state. It just seems less messy to me. As you still need to reach the location associated with a profile I am sure there is a more optimal solution, but I believe this approach is better than the proposed:

```
Profession.joins(:orders).where(orders: {profile: {location: {city: "Simferopol"}}})
```